# How to draw multiple plots with seaborn factorplot?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have dataframe as:

[image]

I want to create a factorplot using seaborn as shown below:
[image]

The data is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jOwjxRYHNVd-8KPnX7zVJOXEn9CAEQ1WKToYxMYazDs/edit?usp=sharing).

Note: Sleep time in the sown graph = Back-end Service Delay (ms)

My existing code is shown below, I do not know how to proceed with it. Any help is much appreciated.

```
def save_multi_columns_categorical_charts(df):
   )
    # add_chart_details(title, filename)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    all_columns = df['Throughput (Requests/sec'),'Back-end Service Delay (ms)', 'Concurrent Users','Scenario Name','Message Size (Bytes)']
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what I had to do was use melt:

```
df_results = df_results.melt(id_vars=['Concurrent Users', col,'Scenario Name','Back-end Service Delay (ms)'],
                        value_vars=['Throughput (Requests/sec)'])

df_results['new_var'] = df_results[col] + ' - ' + df_results['Scenario Name']

g = sns.factorplot(x="Concurrent Users", y='value',
                           hue='new_var', col='Back-end Service Delay (ms)',
                           data=df_results, kind=kind,
                           size=5, aspect=1, col_wrap=2, legend=False)
```